# How to reset style property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

After running the transition property of the div element (with `class="quote"`) using JavaScript, the element fails to reset to its original position for subsequent runs. I have tried using `document.querySelector(".quoteTransition").style.removeProperty("transition");` for JavaScript and `$(".quoteTransition").css("transition", "");` for jQuery to undo the transform and transition properties.  Both seemed to work, but their desired transition effect just before their removal is not seen. How can I correct this?
Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrightJovanny/2y3zxk6g/2/) and [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brightjovanny/pen/PoZqwgW) Snippets. **Please view in a 320px wide screen to see the transition**

HTML Code

```
<div class="preNavBar maxWidth-600" id="maxWidth-600">
        <div class="quote" id="quote">Quote 1: A person who won't read has no advantage over one who can't read. A person who won't read has no advantage.<span class="quoteAuthor" id="quoteAuthor">&#8212; Mark Twain</span></div>
        <div class="quote" id="quote">Quote 2: No matter how tough things are, never give up trying to save another life. Think on this thing.<span class="quoteAuthor" id="quoteAuthor">&#8212; Bright Jovanny</span></div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
font-size: 16pxm;
background: rgb(53, 54, 58);
line-height: 1.2;
}

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.preNavBar {
background-color: navy;
color: white;
display: grid;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}

.maxWidth-600 {
height: 45px;
padding: 3px 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.quote{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.quote.quoteTransition{
overflow: visible;
}

.quoteAuthor {
font-weight: bolder;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
        var i;
        var quote = document.getElementsByClassName("quote");
        const quoteTimeout_default = 5000;  //set timeout to 5seconds
        const quoteTransitionDelay = 2;         //delay transition for 2seconds
        var quoteClientHeight;
        var quoteScrollHeight;
        var searchBox = document.getElementById("searchBox");
        var searchClose = document.getElementById("searchClose");

        showQuote();
        function showQuote() {
            for (i = 0; i < quote.length; i++) {
                quote[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            let min = 0;
            let max = quote.length - 1;
            let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

            quote[randNum].style.display = "inline-block";

            quoteClientHeight = quote[randNum].clientHeight;
            quoteScrollHeight = quote[randNum].scrollHeight;


            if (quoteScrollHeight > quoteClientHeight) {

                quoteTimeout = quoteTimeout_default + (quoteScrollHeight - quoteClientHeight) * 0.05 * quoteTimeout_default;
                //Adding the transition class to the quote element
                document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[randNum].classList.add("quoteTransition");
               //Defining transform and transition to the quote element
                document.querySelector(".quoteTransition").style.transform = "translateY(" + -(quoteScrollHeight - quoteClientHeight) + "px";
                document.querySelector(".quoteTransition").style.transition = "transform " + (quoteTimeout / 1000 - quoteTransitionDelay) + "s " + "linear " + quoteTransitionDelay + "s";
              // Remove style property to reset element
              //document.querySelector(".quoteTransition").style.removeProperty("transform");
                //document.querySelector(".quoteTransition").style.removeProperty("transition");
                /* $(".quoteTransition").css("transform", "");
                $(".quoteTransition").css("transition", ""); */

            } else {
                quoteTimeout = quoteTimeout_default;
            }

            setTimeout(showQuote, quoteTimeout);

            document.getElementById("clientHeight").innerHTML = "Client Height: " + quoteClientHeight + " px";
            document.getElementById("scrollHeight").innerHTML = "Scroll Height: " + quoteScrollHeight + " px";
            document.getElementById("timeout").innerHTML = "Time-out: " + quoteTimeout / 1000 + " sec";
        }
```